# Fingerprint reader on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, biometrics

The fingerprint reader in my laptop (**HP DV6 2005AX**) isn't working in Windows 8. I think I had **DigitalPersona** drivers back in Windows 7. Their site shows that drivers for Windows 8 are not yet available. Is there a way to use my fingerprint reader in Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver for Windows 7 does work, but the part you are missing is the logon screen tie-in app.  Since the logon screen in Win8 is very different, the Windows 7 HP protect tools and others do not work with it.  I tried installing HP protect tools and it hosed the system (the logon screen wouldn't even load).

I recommend waiting for an official Win8 compatible driver/app combo.

Answer (score 5):

The way it worked for me (HP 6570b, Windows 8 x64, Validity VFS491): I did a clean Windows installation without HP software (bloatware?) like ProtectTools and the rest.

All you need to make fingerprint work with Windows is:

- Install [the driver from HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5212927&prodNameId=5212928&swEnvOID=4132&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-112146-1)
- Install latest software [directly from Validity](http://www.validityinc.com/uploads/hp/bnb/WBF/). Drivers are also included – maybe it works without HP driver installed, which I didn't test. I installed the latest available which was `Windows_WBF_Validity_FMA_Setup_4_5_105_1.zip`.

After installation go to *Control Panel » All Control Panel Items » Biometric Devices* and enroll your fingers…

Comment: Since Validity removed links from their site, here is mirror https://mega.nz/#!YotznCLL!bc0amBSuE5SBCKcZhE4t8haIAKZD03YGMmuCEZHqIZ4

Answer (score 0):

[You can try this Validity fingerprint driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-109892-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5276635&sw_lang=) (which yours has the Validity sensor), see if it gets the sensor recognized in Device Manager.

[Or try your original Windows 7 driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-75237-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=4039727&sw_lang=), some drivers for W7 work in W8.

Digital Persona is the Software to set up fingerprints and security and [this W7 software](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-82207-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=4039727&sw_lang=) might also work.

You need both the Driver and Software to make it work.

This is experimental on your part though.

HP is only working on qualifying and releasing Windows 8 drivers for notebooks sold after 10/1/2011 at this time, it is unknown at this point if earlier models will have any W8 drivers released.